# Map mouse coordinates to QGraphicsScene coordinates

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a `QWidget` with a `QGraphicsScene` member. What I to do is for the `QWidget` to receive a `mousePressEvent` (by overloading) and then find a graphics item in the scene from the mouse coordinates supplied by the event.

So my question is how do I convert the mouse coordinates to graphics scene coordinates so I can compare to the graphics item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [QGraphicsView::mapToScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene) to convert the mouse position to the coordinates system of your scene.